# How do I break down large XPaths in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm writing some product exports in XSLT and I have some fairly large select statements, as I have these sort of nested sorts/headers

Given a select statement such as...

```
/objects/object/items/item[
    not(
        custom_options/custom_option[bracelet_piece='engraving_style']/value = preceding::item[
            (
                custom_options/custom_option[bracelet_piece='engraving_style']/value = 'Black Engraving'
                or custom_options/custom_option[bracelet_piece='engraving_style']/value = 'Laser Engraved'
            )
            and not(product_type='configurable')
            and (
                product_attributes/product_type='Dog Tag'
                or product_attributes/product_type='Other Engraveable'
            )
        ]/custom_options/custom_option[bracelet_piece='engraving_style']/value
    )
    and (
        custom_options/custom_option[bracelet_piece='engraving_style']/value = 'Black Engraving'
        or custom_options/custom_option[bracelet_piece='engraving_style']/value = 'Laser Engraved'
    )
    and not(product_type='configurable')
    and (product_attributes/product_type='Dog Tag' or product_attributes/product_type='Other Engraveable')
```

Is it possible to break sections of the statement down into reusable strings that will be evaluated at runtime?

It sounds almost as if I want Attribute Value Templates, but what I could find of those says they can't be used in select statements

To pull the easiest and probably less useful example out of the above, let's say I wanted to be able to include `not(product_type='configurable')` in the select statement without copying the text each time, is there a way to do that?

**Note**: I can't store the result of that section here, as this is a select in a for-each directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you mention attribute value templates and I guess you are talking about `select` attributes then you might want to learn that in XSLT 3 (a W3C recommendation since June of this year) and available with [Saxon 9.8](https://www.saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml) for Java, .NET and C++/C and with [Altova](https://www.altova.com/download) XMLSpy/Raptor 2017 or 2018 you can use so called [shadow attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#shadow-attributes) (i.e. `_select` instead of `select`) with [static variables or parameters](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#static-params)

```
<xsl:variable name="exp1" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="&quot;not(product_type='configurable')&quot;"/>
```

and then you can use e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each _select="/objects/object/items/item[{$exp1}]">
```

You can also with XSLT 2 and 3 define your own functions e.g.

```
<xsl:function name="mf:exp1" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="item"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="not($item/product_type='configurable')"/>
</xsl:function>
```

and then use

```
<xsl:for-each select="/objects/object/items/item[mf:exp1(.)]">
```

(that of course requires binding the prefix `mf` or any prefix you want to use to a namespace for your functions e.g. `xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"`).

Comment: Oh!  Functions, of course.  That seems pretty obvious in hindsight.  Thanks!

Comment: Update: I'm stuck with XSL v1 - so functions don't work for me.  I think that may just be an insurmountable limitation

Comment: Some XSLT 1 processors have support for some extension to XSLT 1 to define functions, like http://exslt.org/func/index.html or extension functions using some scripting language, but in general given XSLT 1 and XPath 1 there is not much you can do. So which XSLT 1 processor do you target?

Comment: I use what's built into PHP.  The docs say that it uses libxslt and links to http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/